# Using wash_out along with dynamic field mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, wash-out

I´m trying to build a Rails 4+ SOAP webservice with the wash_out gem and things look pretty straight forward. What I need is simply output an array of records fetched from a rails model, the complexity comes because my model is actually a MongoDB document with no fields declared. This table can potentially hold any kind of key/value/datatype data that I manage elsewhere in my system.

As I understand, to make use of a ReusableTypes in wash_out you need to specify the field map for that specific type which in my case could be different from one record to another.

Any ideas on how to sort out this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP doesn't work like that. It can only work with fixed structures. Even if you make your DSL update on a per-request basis with ugly hacks, clients still won't be able to work like that. Never use SOAP and Mongo together.

Comment: Guess I´ll have to workaround that. Thanks for your help dude.